# iron:router Meteor how to change route (save state in history) without changing the url

Tags: meteor, browser-history, iron-router

I am developing a `meteor applicaton` . For routing I am using `iron:router` . 
I am changing some templates by changing  a session variable.

Is there any way that without changing the url the user gets an entry in the browser history, that with a browser back the session variable changes back?

My Problem is: Some beta testers tested the app and tried to close some overlays they opened with the browser back button.

Comment: My question is, how do you activate a change in the path using session variables? For example, i want the path add "/modal" at the end when Session.get "Modal", true ... how  can that be done?

Comment: Have you solved this problem yet? I've come across the same problem and I'd like to know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question 100%. But it sounds like you want to set a session variable to a specific value based off of a specific route to control the state of an overlay?

If that's the case, your best bet would be to use an [onBeforeAction hook](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#hooks).

Here's how you could do that with a [Route Controller](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#creating-route-controllers):

```
PostController = RouteController.extend({
  waitOn: function () {},

  data: function () {},

  onBeforeAction () {
    Session.set('someSession', 'someValue');
  },

  action: function () {
    this.render();
  }
});
```

If you don't want to use a Route Controller, you can also just add a hook function and specify a route for which the [hook should run on](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#applying-hooks-to-specific-routes).

**Edit**

```
Router.onBeforeAction(function () {
  Session.set('showOverlay', false);
  this.next();
});
```

You can also specify routes that you don't want this before hook on:

```
Router.onBeforeAction(function () {
  Session.set('showOverlay', false);
  this.next();
}, { except: ['admin'] });
```

Comment: can I change the route without changing the url? For example, I have a page: /post/postHash and have a navbar that opens an overlay/modal e.g. for displaying the users profile. But as this can be displayed on top of nearly every route/page, I do not want to add an extra route for that. But as some of my users are used to use the back button to go to the previous view, I want the app to close the modal on clicking on the browsers back button.

Comment: @Tobi So in other words, when a user either clicks the back button or clicks on another link within the app to go to another route, you want the overlay with the user profile to close, right?

Comment: Jap. But without having a separate url for the overlayed page, because the overlay can be shown on every page.

Comment: The displaying is no problem. I know how to do hooks and so on. The problem is that the hook seems not to be saved in the history as the route doesnt change. e.g. route1 => route1 with overlay => route1 is each the same url.

Comment: @Tobi I would recommend showing some code that replicates the problem, stating what the current behavior is, and stating what the expected behavior is. I'll be happy to give you an answer if you can do that.

Comment: First Pageload: Some Overview Page, Url: (/item/0987u239reu/overview)
User clicks a button, e.g. a modal is shown, Url does not change: (/item/0987u239reu/overview) When the user hits the browser back button, the modal should close (e.g. the "first" page should be shown)